# How can I search from string1 to string2 in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm writing a bash script that will download the page then search for a jpg links and will download them. I'm stucked with grep/sed commands, can't make them find the links. So far I've tried:

```
grep -e "http.*" -e ".*jpg" -n wget.html
```

and

```
sed -n '/http/,/jpg/p' wget.html
```

How can I search from http:// to jpg in linux? Or maybe there's another way other than sed,grep?

Comment: grep -e "http.*" -e ".*jpg" -n wget.html and sed -n '/filmix/,/jpg/p' wget.html

Comment: bash is not a good tool for this.

Comment: What other options do I have for linux?

Comment: @Crazy_Bash perl,awk,ruby, python :) and many more depending on the distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to extract all http://...jpg strings from some downloaded HTML. I guess ideally one per line.

```
$ cat wget.html | grep -e 'http:.*jpg' |sed -e 's/^.*\(http:.*jpg\).*$/\1/g'
```

The grep picks out only lines that contain http refs, the sed strips out all other junk from those lines.

This is limited to one http ref per HTML line.  If that can't be assumed, you could add something like "tr '>' '\010' at the beginning of the pipeline to split up lines with multiple tags.

Example:

```
sal-xps:~  $ cat wget.html
<body>
 <img src="http://foo.jpg">
 <img src="http://bar/gronk.jpg">
</body>


sal-xps:~  $ cat wget.html | grep -e 'http:.*jpg' |sed -e 's/^.*\(http:.*jpg\).*$/\1/g'
http://foo.jpg
http://bar/gronk.jpg
```

Comment: Can I set to a unique output? for example if the page contains two times http://foo.jpg and http://foo.jpg it will show me the link only ones

Comment: There isn't any need for `cat` and `grep`. You can simply do `sed -ne 's/^.*\(http:.*jpg\).*$/\1/gp' filename` to get the result.

Comment: This will be incorrect if there are multiple URLs on the same line.